# Executing 10 functions at a time in python and then restarting the job using threads

Tags: python, multithreading

What i am trying to do is have a function execute 10 times at a time, using threads, and then once they are all done start another group of 10 threads until the program breaks out of a for loop. Currently the steps to my program are

1. User inputs a file
2. python reads file using readlines() which converts it to an array
3. loop through first 10 items using a for loop (for card in cards:)
4. start 10 threads
5. Check when the threads are done, and restart the 10 threads to loop

My current code is

```
def parseFile(file_name, store):
    file = open(file_name, 'r')
    numbers = file.readlines()
    if store == '1':
        for number in numbers:
            for i in range(10):
                x = threading.Thread(target=function(number), args=(1))
                x.start()
                x.join()

def function():
   dostuff
```

This approach doesnt work because it just calls the function once. I have been looking at possibly using a thread pool but I couldn't find any info on restarting the threads on completion

Comment: In your current code, `function` and `card` are undefined.

Comment: sorry I changed the variables around when i posted updated

Comment: Ok, then you need to instanciate the thread like so `x = threading.Thread(target=function, args=(number,))`.

Comment: You also want to make a list of threads so that they are all started, then we wait for all of them to stop. Currently your are doing 10x (start, wait until it's stopped) instead of 10x start then 10x wait. Before the `i` loop, you need `threads = []` and inside the loop you want `threads.append(x)` and get rid of `x.join()`. After the `i` loop you want `for thread in threads: thread.join()`.

Comment: if you are using multithreading with python, you should take a look to this https://realpython.com/python-gil/